# Game server. Moving object over time

Tags: sockets, coordinates, real-time

guys. I have a general question. Let's imagine a simple game scenario.
We have a 2d map where players are located. Players can move and fire rockets. If rocket reaches another player, some action must happen (for example, death).

So we have a server, where the information about current situation is stored:

- Game objects (players, rockets)
- Coordinates of these objects
- Speed of objects
- Coordinates, where currently each object moves (destination point)

We have a client, which is getting information from server via sockets and draws map with objects for a player. Client also sends information to server (when, for example, player clicks on the map - to send data about he's new destination point).

So the question is - how to realise the mechanics of object movement on the server-side? How to detect when two objects are contacting (for example: rocket's position = player's position)?

My idea is:
To make a timer (with a very short interval). After this interval, we need to calculate position of every object on the map depending on it's current position, speed and final destination and to send data via socket to the client. But intuition tells me that it's a really bad approach. If my timer's period is 10ms:

- Tons of data will be sent to the client (and may be will be lost because ping of player in many cases will be bigger than 10ms)
- Server will be overloaded by a lot of calculations each 10ms.

What is the best way to realise my idea?
Maybe there is an article which describes how to do it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/fpm1.html

here, tutorial on netcode, with prediction and interpolation explained, plus code and a live demo

Comment: You may have better luck with this question over on [programmers.se].